# Why can two threads with one lock use CPU more than 100%

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, cpu

I'm working on a multi-core machine and the OS is Ubuntu.

I write a C++11 code as below:

```
thread t1([](){
        while (true) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mutex);
        }
        });
thread t2([](){
        while (true) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mutex);
        }
        });

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

As you see, two thread, one lock. So the two thread will be assigned onto two core, this is for sure.

However, after executing this program, I use `top` to check its usage of resource.

I found that the usage of CPU was about 180%.

As my understanding, only one thread can be executed at any moment because of the `lock`. So why could it use CPU more than 100%?

Comment: Have you considered the expense of acquiring and releasing the lock?

Comment: The percentage is per core. So a four-core system can go up to 400%.

Comment: The mutex is only locked for a fraction of the time in the loop, so there is about 20% waiting, but then 90% of each core is setting up and tearing down the `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: How do you measure CPU usage?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis  `top`

Comment: When one thread is "executing", as you say, the other thread will likely be in a [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) (so it is still running). Depending on the implementation, it may only go to sleep after unsuccessfully waiting in the spinlock for a certain time.

Comment: Your assumptions are not defined by C++. When you create two threads, its not C++ defined on where they would go or if they would go to two CPUs. It's OS dependant.  The same about CPU usage.